# Why my web browser always downloads the .php page rather than show it?

Tags: centos, php

I installed a CentOS7 system in VMware Workstation. The host machine's OS is Win7;
I compiled and installed apache2 (httpd) and MySQL in CentOS, and they both work well, I mean I can visit the index.html page from the host machine's web browser. Then I did

1. `wget` php-5.5.37.tar.gz
2. `tar` it
3. `configure` it
4. then `make` and `make install` it.

The configure commmand is like this:

```
[root@localhost:~/Downloads/php-5.5.37]# ./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/php \
--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql  --enable-fpm
```

In `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` , I added `Include conf/vhost/*.conf`;
And then I created `/usr/local/apache2/conf/vhost/php.conf`, edited it like this:

```
Listen 192.168.1.211:80
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.211:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/www/phpdir
    ServerName www.phphost.com
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/www/phpdir">
        AllowOverride None
        Options Indexs FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I configured IP like this:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.211/24 up
```

I issued `apachectl -t`, the output is OK;

Then I typed `apachectl restart`, everything goes well;
I create a test.php in /usr/local/apache2/www/phpdir, it contains:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

But when I typed `http://192.168.1.211/test.php` in the host machine's web browser's IP address bar , the page didn't show up as I expected. It turned up a download dialog , instructing me to download the page test.php. I guess that's because I didn't configure something, so httpd doesn't know where to find the php engine, right? What can I do ?
By the way , I installed php in /usr/local/php.

**EDIT : 1**

`httpd.conf` content:

```
root@javis:/usr/local/apache2/conf$ grep -v ^# httpd.conf

ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"
Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>


ServerAdmin you@example.com

ServerName 192.168.1.210:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module> 
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>

</IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz


</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include conf/vhost/*.conf
root@javis:/usr/local/apache2/conf$
```

Comment: can you please post your `httpd.conf` file ?

Answer (score 1):

Correct AddType for php is `application/x-httpd-php` in `httpd.conf`

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

Also make sure your php module is loaded

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php55.so
```

When you're configuring apache then try to view the page from another browser - I've had days when chrome stubbornly caches the result and it keeps downloading the source code while in another browser it's just fine.

You might have to do

```
$ a2enmod php5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server does not have the php interpreter running. You need to install php before the web server will try to execute the php code.

```
sudo yum install php
```

Restart apache for good measure (i think this might happen already in the installation of php though)

After this is installed your `php` pages should render as php and not be treated as plain text.

Comment: I think you are right. The php interpreter is not running , so the test.php is treated as plain text. But I have compiled and installed php in /usr/local/php. How can I start php , and let Apache know where to find the php interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

If you really have

```
    ServerName www.phphost.com
```

in that `VirtualHost` definition in your `httpd.conf`, it will only be used if the request is for a page on that domain, but your test asks for a page on `192.168.1.211`.